# How to avoid slow response by set-process-sentinel to process that produces many lines of output

Tags: subprocess

I am running a command that produces a few thousand lines of output,
which I would like to store in a buffer. I want to run it in the
background and be alerted when it is finished. The problem is that it
typically takes of order 10 seconds to report back, when the command
itself takes a second or less to run.

Here is a trivial example. I set up my command to produce 2000 lines
of output

```
(setq bjm-cmd "find /Users/bjm/ -ls | head -2000")
```

then use following to save the output to a string and write to a
buffer

```
(progn
  (message "shell-command-to-string")
  (message (format-time-string "%c" (current-time)))
  (with-temp-buffer (insert-string
                     (shell-command-to-string bjm-cmd)))
  (message (format-time-string "%c" (current-time))))
```

This works effectively instantly.

Now if I instead run the command asynchronously:

```
(defun bjm-test-sentinel (process event)
  (if (string= event "finished\n")
      (message "finished")
    (message "failed"))
  (message (format-time-string "%c" (current-time))))

(progn
  (message "start-process-shell-command")
  (message (format-time-string "%c" (current-time)))
  (setq bjm-proc (start-process-shell-command "dummy" "dummy" bjm-cmd))
  (set-process-sentinel bjm-proc #'bjm-test-sentinel))
```

it takes about 15 seconds to complete.

I presume this is because the sentinel is parsing the output in some
way - right?

My work around is to redirect the output of my command to a file and
then read the file into the buffer. i.e.

```
(setq bjm-cmd "find /Users/bjm/ -ls | head -2000 > /tmp/junk")
```

This runs quickly, but feels like a bit of a hack - is there a better
way?

The context for this is that I am working on a package to call OS X
spotlight using the ivy and counsel libraries, but I think the
question is a generic one.

Comment: For me, running a command that produces 10,000 lines of output takes 9.4 seconds to finish synchronously, and 9.4 seconds to finish asynchronously. What type of system are you on, and what emacs version?

Comment: It's not about the sentinel — the sentinel is run when the process exits. You might be thinking about a filter function, which would receive the output as it arrives from the process.

Comment: @JordonBiondo that is interesting. By default I am running emacs 24.4 on OS X 10.10.5. I am using the emacsformacosx build. I also tested with the macports build of emacs 24.5 with the same result (also starting emacs with `-Q` gives the same result).

Comment: @legoscia I see what you mean. I guess it is whatever part of emacs that is watching for the process to change state that is bothered by the fact that the process is generating many lines of output. Redirecting the output of the shell command to a file or `/dev/null` makes it run just as fast as with `shell-command-to-string`; I am puzzled!

Comment: @JordonBiondo I have now tested on a linux machine running emacs 24.4 and the problem goes away so this appears to be a bug associated with emacs on the Mac. Thanks for the help.